# What is the proper way of using python requests, `requests.request("GET",...)` or`requests.get`?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm learning Python `requests` through a book I purchased. From the book and from the websites I researched, it states this is the proper way to perform a GET request.

```
requests.get(url, params={key: value}, args)
```

In PyCharm it also shows the same thing.

However, when I use Postman to test and look at the sample code it shows:

```
requests.request("GET", params={key: value}, args
```

I'm not sure if I should use `request.get` or requests.request("GET",`
and why choose one over the other.

Comment: They are the same. Check the requests docs: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request

Comment: Note that `requests` isn't a standard Python library. With third party libraries, always check the documentation, the page @GinoMempin references has it all.  `requests.get` is effectively shorthand for a `.request()` call with `'GET'` and as the documentation mentions, its `**kwargs` are passed on to a `.request()` call.

Comment: Always check the docs, third party library or not.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct and will work the same.

The best way to clear up this confusion is to look at the [`requests` source code](https://github.com/psf/requests).

Here is the code for [`request.get`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/v2.25.1/requests/api.py) (*as of 2.25.1*):

```py
def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
    r"""Sends a GET request.
    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param params: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples or bytes to send
        in the query string for the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
    """

    kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
```

...which shows that `requests.get` just calls `requests.request` with a hardcoded `'get'` for the 1st argument. All the other parameters (`url`, `params`, `**kwargs`) are all just passed through.

Basically, **it is just a convenience method** or a shorthand or a shortcut so you don't have to manually remember which string to pass for the `method` parameter. It's easier especially when using an IDE because your IDE's IntelliSense can help you select `.get` or `.post` or `.delete`, etc. but not the raw strings `"GET"`, `"POST"`, or `"DELETE"`, etc.

The `requests` docs can also offer some clarity.

- [`requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request)

  It says "*Constructs and sends a Request.*". So this one is for *ANY* type of request, and you need to pass in 2 required arguments: the `method` and the URL. All the possible `kwargs` are listed in the doc, including the `params` from your example.
- [`requests.get(url, params=None, **kwargs)`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.get)

  It says "*Sends a GET request.*". So this one is more specific in that it is *only* for a GET request. It only has 1 required argument, the URL. No need to pass `"GET"`. And then `kwargs` is "*Optional arguments that `request` takes.*" which just points back to the main [`requests.request`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request) method.

**I would say it's a matter of opinion and coding style which one to use.** A use-case where it makes sense to prefer `requests.request` is when wrapping different API calls and providing a Python interface for them.

For example, I have these APIs:

- GET /api/v1/user/[user-id]
- PATCH /api/v1/user/[user-id]
- DELETE /api/v1/user/[user-id]

When implementing `get_user` and `update_user` and `delete_user`, I could just call the `.get`, `.post`, `.delete`, etc. methods. But if calling these APIs required passing in many and/or complicated `kwargs` (`headers`, `auth`, `timeout`, etc.), then that would lead to a lot of duplicated code.

Instead, you can do it all in one method then use `requests.request`:

```
def get_user(user_id):
    return call_api("GET", user_id)

def update_user(user_id, user):
    return call_api("PATCH", user_id, user=user)

def delete_user(user_id):
    return call_api("DELETE", user_id)

def call_api(method, user_id, user=None):
    # Lots of preparation code to make a request
    headers = {
        "header1": "value1",
        "header2": "value2",
        # There can be lots of headers...
        "headerN": "valueN",
    }
    timeout = (1, 30)
    payload = user.json() if user else {}

    url = f"/api/v1/user/{user_id}"
    return requests.request(
        method,
        url,
        headers=headers,
        timeout=timeout,
        json=payload,
    )
```

There are probably other ways to refactor the code above to reduce duplication. That's just an example, where if you called `.get`, `.patch`, `.delete` directly, then you might end up repeating listing all those headers every time, setting up the URL, doing validations, etc.